# Extending Object

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh

New to blender. Working on 3D printed prosthetic. One hand design we have has been scaled for a client. There is a certain part that falls about 1.5 inches to short. The diameter and circumference of the object need remain the same as other parts attach at both ends, but the object is 1.5 inches too short. I need to pull from one face out to elongate it. I do not want to scale it in the Y axis as it distorts the circumference and width. Is there a way to split the object up into cross sections and just extend further down one end? Any help would be appreciated as soon as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Edge loops? try a few of those then extrude

Comment: Select the faces on the end and hit [E].

Answer (score 1):

This would seem pretty trivial to do. Start by going into the properties window (on the left) [image: Properties panel]and into Scene (third icon in the ribbon) > Units. Select imperial. This will allow you to more accurately move things in inches (the exactly 1.5 inches you mentioned). In Edit Mode (hit tab to go to edit mode) select (By right clicking on the surrounding vertexes. Hold shift to select many) the face(s) you want to pull (from what I gather, correct me if wrong, this is the end of something cylindrical).  Next set your coordinates to local (Dropdown right below the 3D  View. By default it says "Global") [image: Coordinate type popup]. This will let you drag facess accurately and elongate the object without skewing it. Now there are two possibilities:

- You are working on a simple cylinder that you don't want to scale along an axis, because it is rotated. Go to an orthographic view from top (numpad 7 followed by numpad 5, if you don't have a numpad, go to View > Top and View > View / Persp / Ortho). Next, grab the axis of the 3D manipulator that is in the direction you want to move the faces (most probably the blue Z axis) and *after* you have started dragging, press and hold shift and control. You can look below the 3D view to see how much the faces move.
- You are working with a more complex shape and simply dragging faces would distort it. In this case you must add geometry to the object. With the faces selected, hit E to extrude and type ".15" (without the quotes) or "-.15" (without the quotes. This will create an extrusion from the faces you wanted with exactly a legth of 1.5 inches.

I hope this helps.